# Angular way of getting val() from a textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have created a button, that when it is clicked I want to get the text from a textarea.  Here is the html.

```
<div class="text-area-container">
    <textarea id="chatBox" class="chat-box" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="button-container btn-group btn-group-chat">
    <input id="comment" ng-click="chat($event)" class="btn" value="Comment"/>
</div>
```

And here is my controller

```
$scope.chat = function($event) {
    var button = $event.currentTarget;
};
```

I get the button from the $event, but how do I get the textarea. I know that I can jQuery it, but that is not the Angular way. How do i do it without jQuery?

Comment: what do you want to do with textarea data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `ng-model` to text area, like:

```
<textarea id="chatBox" class="chat-box" rows="2" ng-model="textModel"></textarea>
```

In controller write `$scope.textModel = "";`

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/620/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Angular is two way data binding. Setting `ng-model` will chain textarea value with controller var.

On controller side:

```
$scope.textArea = "";
```

On view side:

```
<textarea [...] ng-model="textArea">[...]</textarea>
```

On your controller, $scope.textArea will always contain textarea content.

Comment: No worries, I mean when some1 post the same response 3 min after yours, it seems like copy/paste. Anyways ill give u +1 as right answer

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `ng-model`.

```
<textarea ng-model="text" id="chatBox" class="chat-box" rows="2"></textarea>
```

access it with `$scope.text` in js or `{{text}}` in view.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need to know only text area's value I guess it should be binded to some $scope model variable via data-ng-model="MyTextValue":

```
<textarea id="chatBox"  data-ng-model="MyTextValue" class="chat-box" rows="2">}</textarea>
```

so in $scope.chat function you can get access to $scope.MyTextValue.

You can also enable/disable or show/hide control via ng-* attibutes too. In most cases it is enough.

Comment: You example html won't bind `MyTextValue` to `$scope`.  For that you would need to set the `ng-model` attribute.  This will only print out the value of `MyTextValue`.